# InconsistenProjectHierarchyException

Tags: eclipse, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I have a project with sub-projects (https://github.com/i23098/Collections) that compiles correctly on the command-line. When I try to import the project in Eclipse I get an error and tells me to check the log... Checking it, it has:

```
!ENTRY org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core 4 0 2014-11-09 17:03:13.404
!MESSAGE Gradle project hierarchy is inconsistent for '/home/ralmeida/workspace-collections/Collections'
!STACK 0
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable.run(GradleRunnable.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.InconsistenProjectHierarchyException: Gradle project hierarchy is inconsistent for '/home/ralmeida/workspace-collections/Collections'
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.ExceptionUtil.inconsistentProjectHierachy(ExceptionUtil.java:82)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleModelProvider$GroupedModelProvider.getCachedModel(GradleModelProvider.java:339)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getGradleModel(GradleProject.java:634)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getSkeletalGradleModel(GradleProject.java:653)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.wizards.GradleImportWizardPageOne$11.doit(GradleImportWizardPageOne.java:516)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable.run(GradleRunnable.java:105)
... 1 more
Root exception:
org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.InconsistenProjectHierarchyException: Gradle project hierarchy is inconsistent for '/home/ralmeida/workspace-collections/Collections'
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.ExceptionUtil.inconsistentProjectHierachy(ExceptionUtil.java:82)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleModelProvider$GroupedModelProvider.getCachedModel(GradleModelProvider.java:339)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getGradleModel(GradleProject.java:634)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.GradleProject.getSkeletalGradleModel(GradleProject.java:653)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.ui.wizards.GradleImportWizardPageOne$11.doit(GradleImportWizardPageOne.java:516)
at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable.run(GradleRunnable.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

- Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 4.4.1.20140925-1820
- Gradle IDE 3.6.2.201410090835-RELEASE (configured to use gradle wrapper at http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-bin.zip)

Any ideas?

Comment: Just replying to myself... Starting with a new clean eclipse luna sr1 and installing gradle plugin 3.6.2, new workspace, new git clone, and now it's ok. It seems something got wrong during eclipse/gradle plugin upgrades (https://github.com/spring-projects/eclipse-integration-gradle/issues/59).

Answer (score 3):

I just spontaneously ran into this problem myself with a working project.  After a bit of investigation, I found that an incorrect value was written into file:

projectDir/.settings/gradle/org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.prefs

for the key:
org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.rootprojectloc=

I found simply deleting the bogus value corrected the problem in my case

Comment: I had tried reimporting the project a couple times before finding this answer, so I also had to restart eclipse after getting rid of the .settings directory as it seems Eclipse had cached it somehow.